# Convert date from CSV not work

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I try convert date from my csv file, but catch error : Can not convert null to 'System.DateTime' type.

Sample to reproduce error :

```
$some_string = "(PDH-CSV 4.0) (E. South America Daylight Time)(120),\\NA\Process(w3wp_10060)\% Processor Time,\\NA\Process(w3wp_10060)\% User Time,\\NA\Process(w3wp_10060)\% Privileged Time,\\NA\Process(w3wp_10060)\Page Faults/sec,\\NA\Process(w3wp_10060)\Working Set,\\NA\Process(w3wp_10060)\Private Bytes,\\NA\Process(w3wp_10060)\Thread Count,\\NA\Process(w3wp_10060)\Handle Count`n" +
"10/29/2014 09:37:41.056, , , , ,55205888,44847104,26,471`n" +
"10/29/2014 09:37:46.931,0,0,0,0.17039241953890988,55209984,44847104,26,471`n" +
"10/29/2014 09:37:52.806,0,0,0,0,55209984,44847104,26,471`n"

$datasource = $some_string | ConvertFrom-Csv -Delim ','

foreach ($datapoint in $datasource) 
{
    $date = [DateTime]$datapoint.$StrData
    Write-Host $date
}
```

[EDIT]

This way worked:

```
$date = [DateTime]$datapoint.'(PDH-CSV 4.0) (E. South America Daylight Time)(120)'
```

Any suggestion ?

Comment: What is $StrData and where you are defining it?

Comment: The script was ready, I'm trying to fix.

Comment: $CB, you are correct about variable. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The root cause is not using `Set-PSDebug -Strict` or `Set-Strictmode -version latest`. The strict mode has several [sanity checks](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849692.aspx):

- Prohibits references to uninitialized variables (including
  uninitialized variables in strings).
- Prohibits references to non-existent properties of an object.
- Prohibits function calls that use the syntax for calling methods.
- Prohibits a variable without a name (${}).

In the strict mode, you'd get sensible errors like

```
The variable '$StrData' cannot be retrieved because it has not been set.
The variable '$date' cannot be retrieved because it has not been set.
```

instead of confusing

```
Cannot convert null to type "System.DateTime".
```

After specifying the strict mode, it is easy to note that `$StrData` variable is uninitialized and thus attempt to `$datapoint`'s non-existing member is futile.

Answer (score 0):

There is an unanswered question from CB where he is asking for how`$StrData` is populated. You still havent explicitly addressed that but in your edit you have this:

```
$date = [DateTime]$datapoint.'(PDH-CSV 4.0) (E. South America Daylight Time)(120)'
```

Which shows that you want `$strData` to be the column header of the first column maybe. I shall assume that this is subject to change and statically assigning the value is not what you are going for. In that case what you could do is grab the first column name and assign it to `$strData` which will make the rest of the script work.

```
$strdata = $datasource | Get-Member -MemberType NoteProperty | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name -First 1
```

Using `Get-Member` we get the note properties which represent the csv header. Expand the name of the first one would return '(PDH-CSV 4.0) (E. South America Daylight Time)(120)'. That gets assisgned to a variable. Code could be placed after `$datasource` is defined. If this is not what you intended please update your post with more information about `$strData`.